# function not being called, using jquery .delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delegates, declaration

I want to use jquery delegate to call a function, and this works fine:

```
$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", function(){
alert("it works");
});
```

But I also want to be able to use the same function elsewhere. So rather than writing the same function out several times, I can just declare it separately, and call it by name, right?

But written this way, I never see the alert.

```
function alertMe(){
alert("it works");
};

$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", alertMe());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the parenthisis while defining delegate. just give the function-name

```
$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", alertMe);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `.delegate` has been superseded by the [**.on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method. I would recommend you change your code to use it.

```
function alertMe(){
    alert("it works");
}

$("body").on("mouseover", "div", alertMe);
//$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", alertMe) -- old method
//Note the change in postion of selector and event
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to do this:

```
$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", function(){
   alertMe();
   //plug more code down here
});
```

it has advantages, mainly:

- if you want other stuff done after the event, just add it in
- you can call more functions in this form (rather than that single `alertMe()`)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar do you happen to read his post? he wants to call `alertMe()` everywhere, and not just `alert()`. my answer calls `alertMe()` in a callback function, that way, you can call more functions than just `alertMe()`

Answer (score 0):

Creating the common event handler is easy

```
function alertMe(event){
    //you also need to include the event object, for various actions like stopPropagation()
    alert("it works");
};

$("body").delegate("div", "mouseover", alertMe);
```